# Need help for handling files in node express and MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, post

Here I have 5 files as you see. It is todo-list app that shows todos (stored in the data variable located in the todocontroller.js)on the browser and with the input field the app is supposed to add the new input as a todo (item in the array named data). Now the problem is that it does not add the entered value in the list after clicking on the submit button. I don't know what is wrong Does someone can help le to fix it

todocontroller.js

```
    var express = require('express')
    var todoController = 
    require('./controllers/todoController')
    var app = express()
    
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
    
    app.use(express.static('./public'))
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
    app.use(express.json())
    
    todoController(app)
    
    app.listen(3000)
    console.log('Listening to port 3000...')
```

app.js

```
var data = [{item :'get milk'}, {item :'water'}, {item :'electricity'}]

module.exports = function(app){
    
    app.get('/todo', function(req, res){ 
        res.render('todo', {list : data})

    }) 
    
    app.post('/todo', function(req, res, next){
        console.log(req.body)
        data.push(req.body)
        res.send(data)
        next()
        
    }) 

    app.delete('/todo', function(res, req){
        
    }) 
}
```

todo.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Todo list app</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/styles.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Todo list</h1>
    <div id="todo-table">
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Add an item...">
            <button type="submit">Add item</button>
        </form>
        <ul>
            <% for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++) { %>
                <li><%= list[i].item %></li>
            <% } %>            
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

todo-list.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('form').on('submit', function(){

      var item = $('form input');
      var todo = {item: item.val()};

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/todo',
        data: todo,
        success: function(data){
          //do something with the data via front-end framework
          location.reload();
        }
      });

      return false;

  });

  $('li').on('click', function(){
      var item = $(this).text().replace(/ /g, "-");
      $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/todo/' + item,
        success: function(data){
          //do something with the data via front-end framework
          location.reload();
        }
      });
  });

});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "node-js-playlist-master",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "CSS and asset files for the Net Ninja YouTube nodejs playlist",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please describe what "it doesn't work for me" means. Are there any error messages? Does it do something unexpected? What happens?

Comment: What i mean by "It doesn't work for me" is when I add some input in the input area it is not added to the todo-list, there is no changes.